# Experience to see if an accelerated observer detects radiation

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, differential-geometry

I will consider $\textbf{spacetime}$  as $(M,\eta)$ where $M$ is a four dimensional $\textbf{manifold}$ and $\eta$ the metric which in this coordinates
$$
\begin{align*}
  x \colon M &\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^4\\
  p &\mapsto x(p)=(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3).
\end{align*}
$$
is given by
$$\eta=dx^0\otimes dx^0-dx^1\otimes dx^2-dx^2\otimes dx^1-dx^3\otimes dx^3 \tag1$$

An $\textbf{observer}$ is a worldline $\gamma$ with together with a choice of basis
$
O=v_{\gamma,\gamma(\lambda)} \equiv e_0(\lambda) , e_1(\lambda), e_2(\lambda), e_3(\lambda)
$
of each tangent space  $T_{\gamma(\lambda)}M$ where the observer worldline passes, if
$$
\eta(e_a(\lambda), e_b(\lambda)) = \eta_{ab} = \left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & & & \\ & -1 & & \\ & & -1 & \\ & & & -1 \end{matrix} \right]_{ab} \tag2
$$

where $v_{\gamma,\gamma(\lambda)}$  is the tangent vector of the the curve $\gamma$ at the point $\gamma(\lambda)$

Suppose that we have to observers $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ such that in coordinates $x$ their worldlines are given by $\gamma=(\lambda,\lambda,0,0)$, $\gamma'=(\lambda, \cos (\lambda) ,0,0)$  and so we have
$e_0=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_0}, e_1=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}$, $e_0'=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_0},e_1'=\sin (\lambda)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}$

Now let $F$ be the electromagnetic tensor the observer $\gamma$ will measure the  first component of the electric field as $$E_1=F(e_1,e_1)$$
and for the observer $\gamma'$
$$E_1'=F(e_1',e_1')=\sin^2 (\lambda)E_1$$
As we see if an inertial observer $\gamma$ sees a static field  an accelerated observer $\gamma'$ will see a variated field.
My question is, has any experience been made, to check if  an accelerated observer, can absorb energy from the field by using of an antenna when a inertial observer can not ?

Comment: I think you need to define what would constitute "sees radiation". Do you mean "can absorb energy from the field by use of an antenna"?

Comment: yes that is what i mean